# React Native is there an attribute equals to alt on image component

Tags: react-native, react-native-image, react-native-component

Coming from reactjs i was expecting "alt" attribute on the image component that will show text in case the image could not be loaded. 
I read the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) and the closest thing I found is the on error event.

Is there an attribute equal to alt in React Native image component? And what is the easiest way to replace your image with a default text if i don't have the alt attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make such a component yourself, it requires a very minimal amount of code. Here's a basic example:

```js
export default class AccessibleImage extends Component {

    state = {
        error : false
    };

    _onImageLoadError = (event) => {
        console.warn(event.nativeEvent.error);
        this.setState({ error : true });
    }

    render() {
        const { source, alt, style } = this.props;
        const { error } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return (
                <Text>{alt}</Text>
            );
        }

        return (
            <Image 
                accessible
                accessibilityLabel={alt}
                source={source} 
                style={style}
                onError={this._onImageLoadError} />
        );
    }
}
```

This will show the provided `alt` if there was an error loading the image and also use that text as the `accessibilityLabel` for screen readers which is closer to web behaviour.

Comment: Tnx alot! just wanted to make sure i didn't miss something. I wonder why didn't they add the alt property as default behaviour like in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer than the previous if using React Native 0.68+ is to include the alt attribute on an <Image> Component like so

```
      <Image
        style={styles.yourImageStyles}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        }}
        alt={'Alternate text that will be read be screen readers'}
      />
```